# Qt - proper design of application code

Tags: c++, qt

It was hard for me to search for related topic, so here is my question. I started using Qt like two days ago, and therefore I don't have any clue how to make it working (on the code-side).

[offtopic]
Here's some history: at first I thought about separating my application's logic from its appearance. I had some core classes, another ones for GUI (displaying and controlling), and some kind of "bridges" between to, for example, move data from class A which had std::list members to class B : public QAbstractListView, which had QStringList. But I gave up, when I had to use more and more Qt code (HTTP requests, disk I/O, regex). My code started looking like a mess, co I thought about refactoring my code.

(Anyways, is it a good idea to merge these two things - application logic into Qt (sub)classes?)
[/offtopic]

And I came to another problem and it's finally related to question in topic: is it better (say, Qt-way), for example, to have a class with private member QWebPage and some public methods, slots and signals to operate on it or simply to add my functionality in subclass of QWebPage?

Comment: "Anyways, is it a good idea to merge these two things - application logic into Qt (sub)classes ?" I'd say no, but I'm not very experienced with Qt (more than two days though). I always managed to do this (QAbstractModel and friends make the bridge between UI and normal code), but for large projects it might not be the best option. Also, it seems to me that Qt classes are designed to be easily subclassed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inheritance is one of the greatest things of OOP, if used correctly.

A "subclass", in all good OO designs, has to obey a simple rule: IS the child a KIND OF parent? That is usually called, in OOP literature, a "is a" relationship.
And more important: the child has always to do two things: *specialize* a generic behavior, or *extend* the functionality of the father. I consider it a code smell when a subclass does neither.

That said, your decision has nothing to do with Qt, or with what's programatically better or worse. It should make sense.

An example: If you had a QLabel that had to show the score of a game, and only that, it could be a good idea to do something like

```
class MyScoreBoard : public QLabel
{
private:
   int scoreP1;
   int scoreP2;
   Game *_g;
public:
   MyScoreBoard(QWidget *parent = 0) :
       QLabel(parent)
   {
       scoreP1 = 0;
       scoreP2 = 0;
       connect(_g, SIGNAL(scoreChanged(int,int)), this, SLOT(updateScore(int,int)));
   }
public slot:
    updateScore(int a, int b) {
       scoreP1 = a;
       scoreP2 = b;
       this->setText(QString::number(scoreP1) + "x" + QString::number(scoreP2));
    };

};
```

On the other hand, if your scoreboard had some lights on top of it, that should blink whenever the score had changed, if it had one label for each player, that had to change its color depending on the score, then it would be better to create a ScoreBoard class that HAD two labels, HAD two lights, and then implement the intended behavior.

Bottom line is: inherit if it makes sense on your design

[Wikipedia has a good small article about an anti-pattern that appears when inheritance is used without care.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yo-yo_problem)